# Laravel 5.3 Custom Class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Create a custom class in `laravel` when I am call in controller construct then
Auth::user() not return any data

When call from in a function then it's work

Class Code

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries;



use App\User;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Friends;
class AppLibrarie
{
   private static $friends_ids = array();
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$friends_ids=Auth::user();
    }
   public function getfriends(){
  return self::$friends_ids;
}
}
```

And Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\AppLibrarie;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class LiveController extends Controller
{
    protected $lib;
    public function __construct(AppLibrarie $appLibrarie)
    {
        $this->lib = $appLibrarie;
    }
    public function search(Request $request){
         return response()->json($this->lib->searchdata($request->get('query')));
    }
}
```

Comment: Auth::user() always returns a Model of type User, which is an object. You are putting that object into an array. This is wrong that's why you are not getting any data. Use This instead Auth::user()->toArray();

Answer (score 0):

Accessing authenticated user sessions has been deprecated in Laravel 5.3. Here is the paragraph in the upgrade guide

> In previous versions of Laravel, you could access session variables or the authenticated user in your controller's constructor. This was never intended to be an explicit feature of the framework. In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>
> As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor. Before using this feature, make sure that your application is running Laravel 5.3.4 or above:

You will need to rethink your Authentication structure a bit if you are to upgrade